# Removing and modifying elements in an array which is a value for a key in containers.Map MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have an array of keys, k
and a cell with arrays, v
I use containers.Map to map key-value pairs.

```
k = [4,7,9,12];
v = {[3 4 6 7],[1 2 4],[6 3 9 3 4 7],[8 6]};
M = containers.Map(k,v);
```

So, M(9) gives the array [6 3 9 3 4 7]. My question is how can I remove an element from this array, say I want to remove 3 from the array, so that M(9) gives [6 9 4 7]. Note: I don't want to remove the element by it's index (In my application I don't know the index of the element I want to remove.)
I know for a normal array 'a' I can use something like `a(a==3) = []`
or `a = a(a~=3)`
but here when I use `M(9)(M(9)==3) = []` it gives 
"Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression."

I know that this can be done using a temporary variable but I want to know whether there is any other method that is faster than using a temporary variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in MATLAB you can't use two `()` index lookups in a row (because of poor language design IMHO).

Also it's not clear whether you can modify `container.Map` values in-place, and you may have to read it out, modify the array, and then assign it back into the `container.Map`.

> but I want to know whether there is any other method that is more efficient than using a temporary variable.

"more efficient" how? Fewer lines of code? Faster? For something like this I wouldn't worry about it. If you had a 500x500 matrix you were trying to manipulate, maybe that would be worth trying to optimize for speed.

Comment: By more efficient I meant Faster. In the question that is just an example, in my project I have to check thousands of key value pairs.